# Mustache template for separate lists by category Id

Tags: javascript, mustache

Given some JSON data as array of items:

```js
[
  {
    "category": 1,
    "product": "Sugar"
  },
  {
    "category": 1,
    "product": "Oil"
  },
  {
    "category": 2,
    "product": "Spice"
  },
  {
    "category": 3,
    "product": "Salt"
  },
  {
    "category": 3,
    "product": "Eggs"
  },
  {
    "category": 5,
    "product": "Bread"
  },
  {
    "category": 5,
    "product": "Butter"
  },
  {
    "category": 7,
    "product": "Milk"
  }
]
```

How can I render it using Mustache.js, so that the items are grouped by category Id into separate lists, also adding an empty placeholder for missing Id's (4 and 6 in this case), like:

```html
<ul id="category-1">
  <li>Sugar</li>
  <li>Oil</li>
</ul>
<ul id="category-2">
  <li>Spice</li>
</ul>
<ul id="category-3">
  <li>Salt</li>
  <li>Eggs</li>
</ul>
<ul id="category-4">
</ul>
<ul id="category-5">
  <li>Bread</li>
  <li>Butter</li>
</ul>
<ul id="category-6">
</ul>
<ul id="category-7">
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a solution that does involve data transformation to suit Mustache template format, but performs fewer iterations than cjl750's answer below (which does `filter` and `map` for each item):

```js
// fill data array with empty/no products for all categories (max 7 in this case)
for (let i = 1; i < 8; i++)
  data.push({ category: i });

// group by categories and add products
const grouped = Object.values(data.reduce((r, i) => {
  r[i.category] = r[i.category] || { category: i.category, products: [] };

  if (i.product)
    r[i.category].products.push({ product: i.product });

  return r;
}, {}));
```

It will transform the data array to a grouped object array, like:

```
[
  {
    "category": 1,
    "products": [
       { "product": "Sugar" },
       { "product": "Oil" }
    ]
  },
  :
  :
]
```

Now the template can simply be:

```html
<template id="template">
  {{#.}}
  <ul class="category-{{category}}">
    {{#products}}
    <li>{{product}}</li>
    {{/products}}
  </ul>
  {{/.}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to transform your data into a format you can easily map over with Mustache. Once you've done that, the templating becomes fairly straightforward.

Here's the basic approach below:

1. Find the largest category number in your data, and save it as `largestCategoryNumber`
2. Create an array that is `largestCategoryNumber` in length
3. Populate that array with objects where the value of `category` is the array index and the value of `product` is the products from our original data that had that category number
4. Render the template

```js
const data = [
  {
    "category": 1,
    "product": "Sugar"
  },
  {
    "category": 1,
    "product": "Oil"
  },
  {
    "category": 2,
    "product": "Spice"
  },
  {
    "category": 3,
    "product": "Salt"
  },
  {
    "category": 3,
    "product": "Eggs"
  },
  {
    "category": 5,
    "product": "Bread"
  },
  {
    "category": 5,
    "product": "Butter"
  },
  {
    "category": 7,
    "product": "Milk"
  }
];

const largestCategoryNumber = Math.max(
  ...data.map(({category}) => category)
);

const formattedData = [];

Array.from(Array(largestCategoryNumber)).forEach((_, index) => {
  formattedData.push({
    category: index,
    products: data
      .filter(obj => obj.category === index)
      .map(({product}) => product)
  });
});

const templateData = { data: formattedData };

window.onload = () => {
  const template = document.getElementById('template').innerHTML;
  const rendered = Mustache.render(template, templateData);
  document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = rendered;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/0.7.2/mustache.min.js"></script>

<div id="target"></div>

<script id="template" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
  {{#data}}
  <ul class="category-{{category}}">
    {{#products}}
    <li>{{.}}</li>
    {{/products}}
  </ul>
  {{/data}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think we need to change the response according to our needs :

```
const data = response;
 const dataMap = data.reduce((r,v) =>{
    return{
        ...r,
        [v.category]:[
             ...r?.[v.category]||[],
             {product: v.product} 
        ]
    };
},{});
```

in UI:
result dataMap is

```
{
    "1": [
        {
            "product": "Sugar"
        },
        {
            "product": "Oil"
        }
    ],
    "2": [
        {
            "product": "Spice"
        }
    ],
    "3": [
        {
            "product": "Salt"
        },
        {
            "product": "Eggs"
        }
    ],
    "5": [
        {
            "product": "Bread"
        },
        {
            "product": "Butter"
        }
    ],
    "7": [
        {
            "product": "Milk"
        }
    ]
}
```

and we can use in our ui

```
 for (i of Object.keys(dataMap)) {
       // i for category 
      // dataMap[i] for array product
    }
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, what will the Mustache template look like with this data structure?